# Problem with positioning controls using BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

I hope to create a GUI that has its controls centered. So, I used `VBox` to arrange them vertically and a `BorderPane` to center it. However, it doesn't work the way I think it should, and instead the labels are positioned at the right corner of the window.

```
import javafx.application.Application ;
import javafx.stage.Stage ;
import javafx.scene.Scene ;
import javafx.scene.Group ;
import javafx.scene.layout.* ;
import javafx.scene.control.* ;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class Untitled extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Application.launch(args) ;  
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window)
    {
        Label label_1 = new Label("Hello") ;
        label_1.setMinWidth(75) ;

        Label label_2 = new Label("World") ;
        label_2.setMinWidth(75) ;

        Label label_3 = new Label("!!!") ;
        label_3.setMinWidth(75) ;


        VBox v_box = new VBox(10) ;
        v_box.setPadding(new Insets(20)) ;
        v_box.getChildren().addAll(label_1, label_2, label_3) ;

        BorderPane b_pane = new BorderPane() ;
        b_pane.setCenter(v_box) ;

        Scene the_scene = new Scene(b_pane, 300, 300) ;

        window.setScene(the_scene) ;
        window.show() ;
    }
}
```

What is it that's wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use `BorderPane`. Use `VBox.setAligment(Pos.CENTER)`.

Comment: @Sedrick, I tried it. It worked! Thank you very much. However, I want to know, is there any reason to why the method I used didn't work?

Comment: It sounds like your vbox is being expanded to fill the whole area of the borderpane (since there isn't anything else in the border pane). So it is up to the vbox to lay itself out accordingly. Also, the border pane has a center position, but it isn't necessarily centered. It describes its location relative to the other positions.

Answer (score 0):

BorderPane resizes the height of its top and bottom nodes to their preferred heights first.  Then it resizes height of the left and right nodes up to their preferred heights or whatever is left between the top and bottom, whichever is smaller.  The top and bottom nodes always take up the full width of the parent.  The left and right nodes get their width resized up to their preferred widths.  The center gets resized to take up whatever is left within the scene.   Because you didn't place any nodes into top, left, right, or bottom, your center node (v_box) was resized to take up the entire scene because it had no max/preferred widths/heights applied.  So you had a vbox centered in the center pane... but it was the size of the scene... so anything in the vbox shows up aligned based on the vbox's alignment and content positioning properties... which you didn't set either...  When you updated and set the vbox's alignment to Pos.CENTER you told the vbox to put all of its children centered both left to right but also top to bottom.

Comment: Thankyou. But I don't think I quite understand what you're saying. Can you please show some code for better understanding? That would be really helpful

Comment: code wont help...  your question was why it didnt work...  the answer lies in understanding how BorderPane works...   to reiterate... because you didnt put any nodes into top, bottom, left, or right... then center expands to fill up the entire pane.  So.. your vbox is technically centered in the pane... but its size is the size of the entire pane.  The label objects inside the vbox dont take allignment from vbox's parent... they take alignment from the vbox itself...  and in your original code, you didnt set vbox's alignment property...

Answer (score 0):

The `BorderPane` layout grows the center node as needed/permitted to fill the space left over by the nodes at the boundaries. Lacking `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` nodes the `BorderPane` grows the center node (the `VBox`) to its own size. You can easily visualize this by coloring the background of the layouts:

```
v_box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
b_pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
```

To achieve the desired behavior you need to prevent the center node from growing by setting the max constraints.

```
// do not grow beyond the preferred size
v_box.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

Btw: the imho better layout to use to center a single child in a layout would be `StackPane`.